# Alternative coding regarding isConnectingOrConnecting?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

i am new to android and dealing with an app that broadcasts internet connectivity status. I used a method isConnectingOrConnected() which is deprecated. Im unable to fix my code and its confusing . Please look into my code and help me out. Any help is truly appreciated

here's my code for connectivity Receiver

```
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static ConnectivityReceiverListener connectivityReceiverListener;

public ConnectivityReceiver(){
    super();
}


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null
            && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

    if (connectivityReceiverListener != null) {

 connectivityReceiverListener.onNetworkConnectionChanged(isConnected);
    }
}

public static boolean isConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager
            manager = (ConnectivityManager) 
 ClassForListener.getInstance().getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetwork != null
            && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}


public interface ConnectivityReceiverListener {
    void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected);



}
  }
```

and here's my MainActivity

```
  package com.appindia.srikavyanalluri.mybroacasts;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
 import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectivityReceiverListener {

public Button button1;
CoordinatorLayout cl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_1_1);

    checkConnection();

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkConnection();
        }
    });
}
private void checkConnection() {
    boolean isConnected = ConnectivityReceiver.isConnected();
    show(isConnected);
}
private void show(boolean isConnected) {
    String message;
    int color;
    if (isConnected) {
        message = "Internet is Connected! hurray";
        color = Color.WHITE;
    } else {
        message = "Internet is gone :-(";
        color = Color.WHITE;
    }

      Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(cl, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

      View view = snackbar.getView();
      TextView textView = (TextView) 
      view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
      textView.setTextColor(color);
      snackbar.show();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ClassForListener.getInstance().setConnectivityListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected) {
    show(isConnected);




}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[**`isConnectedOrConnecting`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo#isConnectedOrConnecting()) method was **<s>Deprecated</s>** in API level 28.
Apps should instead use the [**`ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback) API to learn about connectivity changes.

Try with

```
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkRequest.Builder builder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
    connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(
            builder.build(),
            new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onAvailable(Network network) {

                   // Active Network

                }

                @Override
                public void onLost(Network network) {

                  // Lost Network

                }
            }

    );
```

Check `this` answer.

> **ConnectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback)**
>   and **ConnectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(NetworkRequest,
>   PendingIntent)**. These will give a more accurate picture of the
>   connectivity state of the device and let apps react more easily and
>   quickly to changes.

Comment: can you please elaborate it ? im confused

Comment: @KaveeNalluri Okay, Which part confusing?

Comment: can we use isConnected() after adding your code? Also that , I dont know what will be returned in methods onAvailable() & onLost() methods. Im not sure if im pasting the code you have given in the correct place.  Im just a beginner, bear with me please

Comment: @KaveeNalluri You can return Network status using `BroadcastReceiver`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50356272/3395198

Comment: i solved it by replacing  isConnectingOrConnected() with  isConnected()